# python: writing to a global variable from separate thread creates a copy

Tags: python, multithreading, callback

I am trying to create a global state variable, which is written in a callback method (event handler).
However, the callback creates a copy (deep) on another memory location, which is not being seen (of course) by the other methods.
Here is the situation

```
class Server:
  def __init__(self):
    self.callbacks=[]
    #create a web server instance to listen to requests
    self.app=Flask("test")

  def add_callback(self, func):
    self.calbacks.append(func)
    self.app.add_url_rule("/test", "test", self.handle_http_request)

  def handle_http_request(self):
    content = request.get_json(silent=True)
    for ca in self.callbacks:
      ca(content)

  def start_server(self):
    #some stuff starting flask here...


class SomeModule:
  def __init__(self):
    self.ws=Server()
    self.ws.add_callback(self.callback)
    self.callback_called=False

  def callback(self, content):
    print "callback executing---"
    print "var addr before callback assign: "+str(hex(id(self.callback_called)))
    self.callback_called=True
    print "var addr after callback assign: "+str(hex(id(self.callback_called)))

  def start(self):
    self.ws.start()
    #send a request to the server using the request library, which invokes all the trigger
    #check the state variable:
    print "var addr before check: "+str(hex(id(self.callback_called)))
    if (not self.callback_called):
      raise Exception("error...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  sm=SomeModule()
  sm.start()
```

The output is then:

```
callback executing---
var addr before callback assign: 0x927910
var addr before callback assign: 0x927930
var addr before check: 0x927910
```

Can anyone suggest me a way how to avoid this?
In c++ its clear how to access pointer and mutex. Here however, I did not manage to find any ways to do a secure write on the variable...

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using multithreading, and not multiprocessing in your tags, I'll still go ahead and post this answer.. Might be helpful for some.

Some objects are [immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), copied as you said. Other variables, such as [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) tend not to be and can be manipulated from functions or threats (not sure if threads only apply to certain cases).

If you pass a `dict` as a parameter to a thread for instance, that variable can be manipulated and that affects the original version of your variable.

However, doing this is risky. There might be update collisions, access violations and in general just hard to keep track of where things happen.

But here's an example of how to pass a `dict` into a thread and present the change. It's crude, but gives you a working example.

```
from threading import *

class server(Thread):
    def __init__(self, o):
        self.o = o
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self.o['test'] = i

test_var = {'test' : 0}
server(test_var)

while len(enumerate()) > 1: # Stupid and oversimplified wait for threads to end.
    pass

print(test_var)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. When I replace the variable self.callback_called with a dict, the memory inspection shows indeed the same location. However, even if the varibale is set to eg.```self.callback_called['done'] = True``` it is seen as False again during the check.  Feeling like I miss something obvious.... :(

Comment: @mojovski Are you printing the variable to quickly? Because in my test I get it working perfectly. Could you paste you trial code over at https://gist.github.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually somewhere else. :( The reason was, that Flask (the Webserver) was started in a separate thread and there some instances are copied for some reason. I did not dig any further, Just avoided to use Flask and switched to cherrypy and started it in a non-blocking mode.
Thinkgs started to work there as expected.

@torxed, thank you very much for your help. It indeed pointed me into the right direction!

Comment: You're more than welcome :) To bad the question wasn't tagged with `Flask`, because I overlooked that in your code :) Glad it all worked out tho!